# Using C++17 to build ios apps?

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, c++17

The latest XCode clang has support for c++17 but I'm not sure if older iOS devices (e.g., iPhone5, iPhone6) would have the `libc++` library to support that. Is there a way to find out if I can use C++17 to build ios apps that supports all supported iOS versions?

Reference:
iPhone5, with iOS12 is still supported
https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/supported-models-iphe3fa5df43/12.0/ios/12.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, to some extent. If you're back-deploying to older OSes, there are things from C++17 you'll be able to use, and others you won't be able to use. Just try using it and you'll get a compiler error if it's not available on your deployment target. This requires telling the compiler your deployment target, which is usually done with `-mios-version-min=<version>` (or similar for other platforms).

Specifically, a feature `X` that is implemented in the system library (`libc++.dylib`) won't be supported on OSes older than the first version that shipped a `libc++.dylib` with support for `X`. Anything that does not require any sort of library support, i.e. that is all implemented in the headers, will work.

We maintain availability markup in the libc++ headers to flag when you're using something that would break on your deployment target. This is done by using attributes like `__attribute__((availability(ios,strict,introduced=<VERSION>)))` on declarations that depend on something in the shared library. The compiler does the rest of the job -- if you try to use a declaration that hasn't been "introduced" in the deployment target that you specify, it will let you know.

**Edit:** I'm using iOS as an example above, but this works for macOS, watchOS and all other Apple platforms.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to '-mios-version-min=<version>', this should work.